# Posix equivalent of LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, size)

Tags: c++, c, libc

I have code which works on windows, that calls [LocalAlloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366723(VS.85).aspx) as follows:

```
LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT, size)
```

I need the equivalent malloc or calloc call to get this to work on Unix systems, through Mono.  Simple answer?

Comment: What do you mean by "through Mono"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm calling this through P/Invoke, but that probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand it just allocs zeroed memory, so a `calloc(1, size)` should suffice to allocate `size` zeroed bytes.

Answer (score 0):

I thought LocalAlloc was deprecated in favor of HeapAlloc?

Either way calloc(), malloc() and realloc(), free() are the POSIX choices for memory management.

You always check the return value:

```
char *retval=calloc(1, sizeof(object type) );
if(retval==NULL)
{
   perror("Memory error");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```